# How to start learning differential equations again?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I finished my engineering career (Electronic Engineering), but I feel that my mathematical knowledge is deficient in important areas (like Fourier series, Laplace, differential equations.. etc).

I'm willing to learn all over again mathematics, but I don't know where to start. Actually did try to understand differential equations on my own but failed miserably.

How can I learn basic and advance mathematical subjects? Any recommended books, websites etc.?

Thanks a lot, and I apologize for my bad English and maths ignorance.

Comment: MSE is a great place! :)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MSE. For Differential Equations with somes applications, I recommend for you two books:

**1.** [Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387951164), by Lawrence Perko

**2.** [Ordinary Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=gsm-140), by Gerald Teschl

Answer (score 0):

I would add the Schaum's Outline series for your particular topic.  The outlines are an excellent mix of some exposition of ideas followed by lots of problems.  For the solved examples the steps to solution are well documented.  I learn best by working examples, but the Schaum outlines are **in addition** to a proper text on the subject not a substitute for a proper text.

Schaum outlines on the topics you mentioned:

[Differential Equations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071824855)

[Fourier Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070602190)

[Tensor analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071756035)

The rest of the [Schaum's outlines](http://www.amazon.com/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=schaum%27s%20outlines&tag=googhydr-20&index=stripbooks&hvadid=31542190977&hvpos=1t1&hvexid=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=14652270750080931818&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=b&hvdev=c&ref=pd_sl_34wey3r9ze_b):